# Menu and Footer shows double in 6.2 by adding / to URL

Tags: migration, aem

while we are moving our code from 5.6 to 6.2, we experience a wired issue, that we have authored Menu and Footer on home page, like /en/home,
and all the header and footer will be inherited to all sub pages under home page, ex: /home/test1, /home/test2..

the issue is, when we hit the URL like , www.testing.com/home/ , then this shows two menus and two footer content, 
but where as if we hit URL with www.testing.com/home it works well,

i understand that AEM thinks, /home/ is a sub page under the home page, that's how it's inheriting the menu and footer content,

not sure any one have experienced this issue this before in 6.2.

Let me know if any have solution for this,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow the request trace to see exactly what's going on.

http://localhost:4502/system/console/requests

Recent request page has some configurable items such as Request Path Patterns, number of requests, etc. Search "Apache Sling Main Servlet" in http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr